# Open Cart 2.0 issues with

Tags: mysql, opencart

oI upgraded to OpenCart 2.0 before they posted a notice not to do so... I have worked out most of the kinks, however, when I attempt to add something to the shopping cart the error log reflects the following:

```
2014-10-23 12:46:00 - PHP Notice:  Error: Column 'customer_group_id' in where clause is ambiguous<br />Error No: 1052<br /> Error in: <b>/home/www/letteritgirl.net/catalog/model/catalog/product.php</b> line <b>495</b><br />
SELECT `pd`.* FROM `oc1_product_recurring` `pp` JOIN `oc1_recurring_description` `pd` ON `pd`.`language_id` = 1 AND `pd`.`recurring_id` = `pp`.`recurring_id` JOIN `oc1_recurring` `p` ON `p`.`recurring_id` = `pd`.`recurring_id` WHERE `product_id` = 999969 AND `status` = 1 AND `customer_group_id` = 1 ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC in home/www/letteritgirl.net/system/library/db/mysql.php on line 53 
2014-10-23 12:46:00 - PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/www/letteritgirl.net/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 495
```

The message stays on loading as if it is stuck in a loop, and nothing is added to the shopping cart.

Line 495 is the following:

```
$product_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_option` po LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option_description` od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id) WHERE po.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND od.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
```

I am stuck on what to do to resolve this issue. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you do an *update* after the community release went out (3-4 weeks ago)? I.e. are you using the stable version right now?

Comment: I am using the stable version - I reinstalled again yesterday.

Comment: Did you also try a clear install? If not, do so. Stable version means stable, such errors should not be part of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you've pasted isn't line 495 in any version I have. Line 495 is this, which also matches up with the query in your log:

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT `pd`.* FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_recurring` `pp` JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "recurring_description` `pd` ON `pd`.`language_id` = " . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . " AND `pd`.`recurring_id` = `pp`.`recurring_id` JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "recurring` `p` ON `p`.`recurring_id` = `pd`.`recurring_id` WHERE `product_id` = " . (int)$product_id . " AND `status` = 1 AND `customer_group_id` = " . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . " ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC")->rows;
```

The error indicates two or more of the tables have a "customer_group_id" field, but that's not true, I checked databases from 2.0.0.0b4 and the current "stable" version. This suggests you have an even older version with different tables. You really shouldn't be using it, there are going to be a LOT of bugs that you might not even notice until it's too late! But to fix your error, just change

```
AND `customer_group_id` =
```

To

```
AND `pp`.`customer_group_id` =
```

in the line I pasted above.

Comment: I apologize - you are correct:
         'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],

is my line 495 and the error does remain... 
I could roll my client back but then I will need to upgrade them again ...

Comment: It's definitely worth the hassle. Opencart 2 is FULL of bugs right now, far too many to be considered for a production site!

Comment: Hmm, all I would say is never upgrade a production site live until you have tested 100% first on a test server.